# org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read while executing tests through Node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am new to Selenium and started learning it. But the Selenium Grid is not working for me. The server version used is selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar. Using command, the hub and node are running.
The code for adding nodes to hub is written using TestNG in Eclipse. The code is as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.WIN10);             
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.xxx.x.xx:48807/wd/hub"), options);             driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
```

While running the test, the following error occurs and the sessions are not created:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: 
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:143)
    at grid.Node2.f(Node2.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read: 
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-
```

Hub Command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub
```

Node Command:
java -DWebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\SWs\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://xxx.xxx.x.x:4444/grid/register/

Browser details : Chrome 69
ChromeDriver 2.42.591088

Anybody please help to resolve this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: Update the question with the _commands_ you have used to initiate the _Selenium Grid Hub_ and _Selenium Grid Node_. Additionally also provide the _ChromeDriver_ and _Chrome Browser_ version details.

Comment: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub

java -DWebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://IPaddress:4444/grid/register/              
                                                           Browser details : Chrome 69      ChromeDriver 2.42.591088

Answer (score 3):

A bit suprised with the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read
```

As per [Selenium 3.12.0 Windows org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Cannot coerce something that is not a number to a number: STRING](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5910) the fix should have been available in **Selenium v3.14.0** with respect the the commit [Allow the number coercer to implicitly coerce strings to numbers](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/1a0f31e2997ea5856696fa4b804483f87d850d08). The error should have been:

```
Cannot coerce something that is not a number to a number: " + type
```

Still as you are using *Selenium v3.14.0* binaries it seems you are using the deprecated functions.

As per the documentation **CapabilityType** of **`PLATFORM_NAME`** is not a valid configuration and you need to change it as **`PLATFORM`**.

On my *Windows 8* system with *Selenium v3.14.0* binaries here is the solution which executes just perfecto:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.URL;

  import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class testChromeOnGrid_test 
  {

      @Test
      public void test1() throws MalformedURLException
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.WIN8);           
          options.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
          WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options);
          driver.get("http://google.com/");
          System.out.println("Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
  Oct 16, 2018 3:00:57 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
  Title is : Google
  PASSED: test1

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================


  ===============================================
  Default suite
  Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```

---

### Update

As per your question update there is an issue with the *Selenium Grid Node* starting command you have used. Use the command as follows:

- To register a *Selenium Grid Node* for *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* you need to pass the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver*  as follows:

  ```
  >java -DWebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://<IP_GRID_HUB>:4444/grid/register/
  ```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. Tried with exactly the same code specified here. But it is not working for me. As specified in your post, 'PLATFORM' is not working. The error is [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
FAILED: test1
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'N315', ip: '192.xxx.x.x', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: I have already asked you previously in a comment to update the question with the _commands_ you have used to initiate the _Selenium Grid Hub_ and _Selenium Grid Node_. Additionally also provide the _ChromeDriver_ and _Chrome Browser_ version details.

Comment: Updated question, please check

Comment: @muzirisrd- Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: I had already done like that. Please find the output obtained 18:28:40.368 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://xxx.xxx.x.x:4444/grid/register
18:28:40.821 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use

Comment: @muzirisrd- You are still overstepping in-case you haven't spotted the difference in the commands. Take a fresh breathe and look at the command again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error today, and while searching for the solution I landed on this page.

The hub and the node are up and running in my machine.
I tried accessing http://localhost:4444/grid/register/ in the browser. which has resulted into following error:
JsonException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read:

Then found that the above URL what I have used is incorrect. Instead I need to use
http://localhost:4444/grid/console

Solution found here on GitHub: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6446

Answer (score 0):

// It could be that grid hub requires authentication

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<user>:<password>@192.xxx.x.xx:48807/wd/hub"), options);
```