# Selenium Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Tags: selenium, centos, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to start Selenium Server

CentOS

```
root@node /var/www/$ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub

09:02:18.529 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
09:02:18,685 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
2021-06-03 09:02:19.257:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1183ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
09:02:19.593 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
09:02:19.595 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://10.100.27.99:4444/grid/register/
09:02:19.596 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://10.100.27.99:4444/wd/hub
```

Error:

> 2021-06-03 09:15:19.432:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp57748372-14:
> /grid/register/ org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Expected to
> read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read: |Build
> info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
> '2018-11-14T08:25:53'|System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1',
> os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0',
> java.version: '1.8.0_292'|Driver info: driver.version: unknown
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.expect(JsonInput.java:290)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.beginObject(JsonInput.java:220)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.MapCoercer.lambda$apply$1(MapCoercer.java:64)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:145)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:126)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:69)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:55)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:50)
> at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistrationServlet.process(RegistrationServlet.java:83)
> at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistrationServlet.doGet(RegistrationServlet.java:64)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
> at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I can't solve the problem: Driver info:

> driver.version: unknown

Comment: I have not done this but looks like driver version issue, is there a way to have inline version of selenium chromedriver in server ? I believe yes

Comment: See if this helps:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830236/org-openqa-selenium-json-jsonexception-expected-to-read-a-start-map-but-instead